# Is this graph cubic? It doesn't look it.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Here are 2 examples relating f(x) to the first and 2nd derivatives.  In both, the first deriv. looks like $x^2$ and the 2nd deriv is linear.  This implies the f(x) is a cubic $x^3$.

Yet, in the 2nd example, it does not look like the typical cubic with the limits going to infinity.  This one is flattening out.   Can f(x) still be considered a cubic?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it can, consider for example [the plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E3%20-%202x%5E2%20%2B%203) of $f(x) = x^3 - 2x^2 + 3$ between $0$ and $\frac{4}{3}$.

Comment: No, my example is flattening with slopes of zero on the ends.  Your example does not do that.

Comment: @JackOfAll It does, you just need to consider an appropriate interval, e.g. $[0, \tfrac{4}{3}]$. See http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E3+-+2x%5E2+%2B+3+from+0+to+4%2F3

Comment: Or, can you edit your response to be from [0, 4/3] and not your incorrect response of [-1,2] ?  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You've only been given information for a limited domain. Within this domain, it appears that we do have a cubic, but we don't know how the function behaves either side of the left and right stationary points...

The quadratic graph looks like $f'(x)=-kx(x-2a) \Rightarrow f'(x)=-kx^2+2kax$

That would integrate to give $f(x)=-\frac k3 x^3+kax^2+c $

Answer (score 0):

Well, it says that $f''$ is in the form $ax+b$ with $a<0$. So, yes: $f(x)$ must be a polynomial of degree $3$, and the flattening is just because you are stopping your plot near two stationary points (which have non reason not to exist, since $f'$ has up to two real roots).